# Uploading Databases

Tags: database, cassandra, file-sharing

How does one go about uploading a database like Apache Cassandra after creating one? Furthermore, is there a way to upload/share only its skeleton structure, without the data gathered in it? I'm on MacOS and would like to use Python to do all of this. Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by uploading? You can get the complete schema output using "DESCRIBE SCHEMEA" command in cqlsh. You can use datastax driver for python to connect to Cassandra database and execute your queries.

Comment: Does upload mean to load the other cassandra's complet schema in the new one? Maybe this question helps you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67639544/how-do-i-replicate-a-cassandras-local-node-for-other-cassandras-remote-node .

Comment: By upload I guess I mean share the database with someone else, or have the Apache Cassandra database be accessible and editable on more than one device. How can I upload or I guess port that to someone else's device?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your second comment, I guessed it to mean you want the database to be remotely accessible to clients/apps not installed locally.

Clients/apps connect to Cassandra on the IP address set for `rpc_address` and the CQL port set for `native_transport_port` (default is `9042`) set in `cassandra.yaml`.

You mentioned that your Cassandra instance is running on your laptop so only clients/apps running on your local network can access it if you configure `rpc_address` to an IP address accessible on the network (default is `localhost`).

If you're just trying out Cassandra and want to collaborate with other developer friends, try [Astra](https://dtsx.io/3oUbsNq) and launch Cassandra instance on the free-tier (no credit card required). With it you can share the database credentials with your friends and they can connect to it over the internet.

You can connect to Astra from your Python app using the [Python driver](https://docs.datastax.com/en/astra/docs/using-the-datastax-python-driver-to-connect-to-your-database.html). Otherwise, Astra includes [Stargate.io](https://stargate.io/) pre-configured and ready to use. Stargate is a data access gateway that lets you connect to Cassandra from your app using REST API, GraphQL API or JSON/Doc API without having to learn CQL. For more info, see [Connecting to your Astra database](https://docs.datastax.com/en/astra/docs/connecting-to-database.html). Cheers!